# Cast WindowExtIOS from Window in Bevy

Tags: rust, bevy, winit

I'm using beau which internally use winit.

I'm running my app in iOS devices so the way I have configured my project winit it should create a `Window` of type `WindowExtIOS`

```
fn setup_raw_window(mut windows: NonSend<WinitWindows>, window_query: Query<Entity, With<PrimaryWindow>>) {
    let entity = window_query.single();
    let raw_window:&window::Window= windows.get_window(entity).unwrap();
    // How to cast to WindowExtIOS
}
```

The problem is that I don't see how to make the cast to WindowExtIOS since even watching with the IDE that the class exist and is in my package, rust and bevy cannot accept the package `winit::platform::iOS`

Any idea what to do?

Regards.